# How to check if elements form a primitive system of a lattice

Tags: primitive, mathematical-lattices, basis

Given a collection of vectors $V = {v_1, v_2, ..., v_k}$ belonging to a lattice $L$ with basis $B$, is there an efficient procedure that can determine whether or not $V$ forms a primitive system for $L$? This means that if $L$ has rank $n \geq k$, you can extend $V$ by adding $n-k$ vectors such that the resulting set is a basis for $L$.

Comment: Please provide code example in order to get help . You can read best practice here [mcve]

Comment: This is not a question that requires an example, rather it asks for an eventual algorithmic proof of principle.

Comment: you may have right, but when i review your question, the first thing that came to me is your question looks like a mess as its not formatted / unclear . May be stackoverflow is not the best place for this, have a look here : http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: If it's not at least marginally clear then this may indeed not be the best place for this question. Thank you for your comment.